# Can someone give intuition behind understanding $i^i = e^{\frac{-\pi}{2}}$ and more so on complex powers?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have no problem accepting that $$i^i = e^{\frac{-\pi}{2}} $$ **Here im assuming that $-\pi\leq \theta \leq \pi$**
But what I am wondering is that, can someone give me some intuition behind understanding taking powers of a complex number where the power is also complex ? Like I am curious what you used to get an understanding of this property ? I chose $i^i$ because it seems like an easy example to give intuition behind but I am also looking at this from the point of view of also trying to understand say: $$(4+5i)^{(2-3i)}$$ Like how do you get an intuitive understanding of this ?

Comment: Look into [Euler's formua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), that should make things more clear:
$$e^{i \theta } = \cos (\theta) + i \sin(\theta).$$

Comment: Also, $a^b = e^{b \ln{a}}$. Understanding complex exponentiation really means understanding the logarithm. And this is a basic topic in complex analysis. It also explains why some calculators give different answers, since definite log outside of the positive reals requires a choice of branch cut.

Comment: @Tac-Tics, while it is true that choosing a "branch cut" makes logarithm unambiguous, doing so is no different from making a fairly random choice, so really is not as explanatory as we'd wish. That is, there is no "canonical" branch cut (although there are traditions, these traditions do not so much reflect mathematical reality as they reflect the impulse to tradition together with an impulse to disambiguate).

Comment: Actually you should "have (some serious) problem(s) accepting that $i^i = e^{-\pi/2}$" since this is not true.

Comment: @Did What I meant by my statement is that I don't have a problem with how you would get to that result, I am aware that I didn't include to periodicity, which is why I said in my question I am taking theta to be between $-\pi$ and $\pi$ I was more or less looking to understand complex powers more intuitively

Comment: Starting with an undefined quantity such as $i^i$ might not be the best approach to achieve this understanding.

Comment: @Did : $i^i$ (or generally $z^w$ for complex $z$ and $w$) is/are about as defined and as undefined as $\mathrm{arctan}$ and $\sqrt{}$ are, which is to say that it is or can be ambiguous, but not so ambiguous as to be anything at all, and thus why you should specify, as was done, what the range of the imaginary part of the implicit complex logarithm you are considering is. Certainly not ambiguous enough to forbid it from use altogether, any more than those other operations are so forbidden. If ambiguity due to its multivalued nature makes it forbidden, then those two should be as well.

Comment: Cuts and ranges in them are just as arbitrary, btw.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Sorry but $\arctan$ and $\sqrt{\ }$ are quite unambiguously defined on their respective domains of definition (the real line and the nonnegative real half line, respectively) so the analogy in your comment does not hold. On this site, users who insist on using $z^w$ with $z$ and $w$ complex, when the problem of the definition of the thing is mentioned, most often seem to suddenly remember that, actually, of course they were thinking of $z^w$ as a set of complex numbers and not as a unique complex number (although they were until then using $z^w$ as ...

Comment: ...  a unique complex number, with no qualms at all). Your take seems to be slightly different but I am not sure what it is exactly. In any case, a sure fact of life is that, in a pedagogical context, one simply cannot raise said definitional problem too much.

Comment: @Did : No, they are not, not even on the reals. $\tan$ is $\pi$-periodic, so its inversion _must_ be manyvalued. The choice of a certain range for $\mathrm{arctan}$ is still a convention, not an absolute, though one could argue it's a little more "natural" to at least pick ranges for which the ends are asymptotes - but in the complexes that extra degree of freedom results in the whole thing becoming totally connected (in topological sense), which takes that away.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer ?? Sorry but nobody considers arctan as being many valued. Are you developing your own brand of mathematics? You may, of course, but if you do, please say so. (If references are needed, even [the obvious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions) works.)

Comment: @Did : Then what is it? If extended to the complex numbers, it definitely ends up as such. Or would you say then that arctan of a complex number is similarly "undefined"?

Comment: @Did : Moreover, your link mentions specifically how that the functions are multivalued and that a principal branch must be taken, and moreover that at least in some cases, the choice of this can vary between some authors. This is the same situation as $\ln$. Perhaps maybe the better way to say it is that there is more agreement on the convention for principal branches of $\mathrm{\arctan}$ than for $\ln$ when the latter is extended to complex input.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Sorry but I think I have had my dose of crankiness for today. All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that the  *intuition* you ask for gets lost somewhere on the way.

We may start by defining $$ \tag 1a^b:=\underbrace{a\cdot \ldots \cdot a}_b$$
for $b\in \Bbb N$ (or maybe define $a^b$ as the cardinality of the set of maps from a set of cardinality $b$ to a set of cardinality $a$, which allows us to use some infinite $b$-values, but poses a restriction on the $a$'s used; for this discussion. I'll stick with $(1)$ as a starting point) and then extend the definition step by step to larger domains, based on a permanence principle: For $(1)$ we prove rules such as $$\tag2a^{b+c}=a^ba^c$$ and extend the definition in  a way that (among others) these rules remain valid. For example, this forces us to define $a^{-b}=\frac1{a^b}$ when extending to $b\in\Bbb Z$ (and which also shows that we *cannot* define $0^b$ for $b<0$).

Sooner or late, the only way of extending the domain is via the exponential function
$$\exp(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!} $$
which is fortunately convergent for all $c\in\Bbb C$ (and even in many situations where $x$ is not even a number, thus allowing us to define exponentiation even in some at the first glance strange areas).
Among the many fascinating properties of $\exp$ is
$$\exp(x+y)=\exp( x)\exp (y),$$
just as needed for $(2)$.
But that requires us to use the inverse function $\ln$ and set
$$\tag3a^b=\exp(b\ln a).$$
This is all fine, but $\ln a$ cannot be defined at for at $a=0$ (thus we better still use $(1)$ instead of $(3)$ in that case) and $\ln$ can only be defined "consistently" in a simply connected domain (not containing $0$). The most common convention(!) to pick  such a domain as large as possible is to remove the non-positive reals from $\Bbb C$. That is, for all other $z$, $\ln z$ is a complex number $w$ with $\exp(w)=z$ and $-\pi<\arg w<\pi$. As $\exp$ is its own derivative, we quickly find that $\exp''(ix)+\exp(ix)=0$ and by comparing the initial conditions, find $\exp(ix)=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$. Hence $\exp(i\frac\pi2)=i$, so that our chosen convention tells us $\ln(i)=i\frac\pi2$ and ultimately $$ i^i=\exp(i\cdot i\tfrac\pi2)=\exp(-\tfrac\pi2).$$
I think it is the forced use of some convention when picking a good domain in $\Bbb C$ which ultimately kills the intuition you are looking for.
Note that I consequently wrote $\exp(x)$, not $e^x$ in order to avoid the idea that the exponential function "is" taking some number dubbed $e$ to some power.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate $z^u=(4+5i)^{2-3i}$ you have to use three formulas

- convert $z=(4+5i)$ from rectangular form to polar form $z=re^{i\theta}$
- calculate $\ln(z)=\ln(r)+i\theta+2ik\pi\qquad k\in\mathbb Z$
- calculate $\displaystyle z^u=e^{u\ln(z)}$

Let's go:

$r^2=|z|^2=4^2+5^2=41\implies r=\sqrt{41}$

Since $z$ is in the first quadrant then $\theta=\tan^{-1}(\frac 54)$

$\begin{array}{ll}z^u &=\exp\bigg((2-3i)\left(\ln(r)+i\theta+2ik\pi\right)\bigg)\\&=\exp\bigg(\left(2\ln(r)+3\theta+6k\pi\right)+i\left(-3\ln(r)+2\theta+4k\pi\right)\bigg)\\ &=r^2\ e^{3\theta}\ e^{6k\pi}\bigg(\cos\big(2\theta-3\ln(r)\big)+i\sin\big(2\theta-3\ln(r)\big)\bigg) \end{array}$

And from there you can calculate a numerical value by replacing $r,\theta$ by their respective value:

> $(4+5i)^{2-3i}\approx e^{6k\pi}\left(-484.77 + 358.42\,i\right)$

---

Note that $\ln(z)$ is multivalued since it is the reciprocal function of exponential which is $2i\pi$ periodic.

So in the end you get a factor $e^{6k\pi}$ and a principal value $[z^u]_{k=0}=-484.77+358.42i$

You need to keep this factor for things like $z^u\times z^v=z^{u+v}$ to stay true.

If you only consider the principal value then $[z^u]_{k=0}\times[z^v]_{k=0}=[z^{u+v}]_{k=0}$ may be false.

You have to see it like $\exists (k_1,k_2,k_3)\in\mathbb Z^3\mid\  [z^u]_{k=k_1}\times [z^v]_{k=k_2}=[z^{u+v}]_{k=k_3}$

---

Now that you understood the principle, let's do it for $i^i$ :

$\displaystyle i^i=\exp\bigg(i\ln(e^{i\frac{\pi}2})\bigg)=\exp\bigg(i(\ln(1)+i\frac{\pi}2+2ik\pi)\bigg)=\exp\bigg(-\frac{\pi}2-2k\pi\bigg)=e^{-\frac{\pi}2}e^{-2k\pi}$

So the principal value is $[i^i]_{k=0}=e^{-\frac{\pi}2}$ and the factor is $e^{2k\pi}$

[*note that since $k$ is arbitrary, $2k\pi$ or $-2k\pi$ does not matter*].

To conclude let's calculate $i^2$. Should it also have multiple values ?

$\displaystyle i^2=\exp\bigg(2\ln(e^{i\frac{\pi}2})\bigg)=\exp\bigg(2(\ln(1)+i\frac{\pi}2+2ik\pi)\bigg)=\exp\bigg(i\pi-2ik\pi\bigg)=\underbrace{e^{i\pi}}_{-1}\underbrace{e^{2ik\pi}}_{1}=-1$

This time it has only one value as expected $i^2=-1$, because the factor $e^{2ik\pi}=1$ for any value of $k$.