# How do I compute $(-i)^i$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Could I please get help computing $(-i)^i$? I know the answer is $$e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-2\pi n}=e^{-2\pi\left(\frac{n-1}{4}\right)}.$$
I can't figure out how to get to this answer.

Comment: What do you mean by solving? It's not an equation. And please use MathJax for formatting: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$

Comment: The usual way to **compute** $x^y$ is $e^{y\log(x)}$, but log is multi-valued in $\mathbb{C}$. That being said, one value for $\log(-i)$ is $-\frac\pi2i$, and using that, we get $(-i)^i=e^{\pi/2}$. However, another value for $\log(-i)$ is $\frac{3\pi}2i$, which gives $(-i)^i=e^{-3\pi/2}$. One must specify which branch of log they are using.

Comment: Use your definition of $a^b$ for complex $a$ and $b$!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446611/can-someone-give-intuition-behind-understanding-ii-e-frac-pi2-and-m/2446755#2446755

Answer (score 0):

Since
$-i 
=e^{3\pi i/2+2\pi i n}
=e^{-\pi i/2+2\pi i n}
$
for any integer $n$
(different $n$s),

$(-i)^i 
=(e^{-\pi i/2+2\pi i n})^i
=e^{i(-\pi i/2+2\pi i n)}
=e^{\pi /2-2\pi n}
=e^{\pi /2}e^{-2\pi n}
=e^{\pi /2}e^{2\pi n}
$
with a different n at the end.

Comment: This seems a nice simple way to get the values on all branches, but you could actually use different letters instead of saying “different $n$”. Two letters would be enough because you don’t really need the $i3\pi/2$ exponent; just go straight to $-i\pi/2.$

Comment: I think you also need to retain the factor $i$ in a couple of those exponents near the end. The previous steps should make this obvious enough, though.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with (-i), we can express it as e^(i * (3π/2)) because cos(3π/2) = 0 and sin(3π/2) = -1.

Now, raise this expression to the power of i. Using the properties of exponents, this becomes e^(i * i * (3π/2)).

Since i^2 = -1, we have e^(-3π/2), which is a real number. So, (-i)^i equals a real number, approximately 1.18.